# 1 to N relationship on a product shop database design

Tags: database-design

imagine this scenario:

I want to run a database that keeps track of all the purchases that every customer makes.
So i'll have a purchases table along a customers table and a prodcuts table.
The thing is that one purchase is made of many objects.
To keep track of this my idea is to make another table objectslist that contains: a primary key as as generic id, a foreign key as the purchaseid that references the purchase table, and the product id as a foreign key from the products table.

The thing becomes tricky for 2 reasons:
inserting a purchase can be troublesome because i've got to update 3 tables at once.
Querying for a specific purchase and all the objects on the cart involves multiple joins and i haven't figured out how to do this yet.

If there's any other simple idea let me know.
Thanks

Comment: You can use a trigger on the relevant tables to perform the updates. If you want an example of a store database you can check out AdvertureWorks for SQLServer or You can download OpenCart (it's a PHP based Open-Source eCommerce store, contains everything you said.)

Comment: Seems like a reasonable design. A purchase may contain many products and a product may appear in many purchases so it's clearly a n-to-n relationship. What's troubling you with joininig multiple tables? As for updating 3 tables at once, that's what transactions are for.

Comment: If you have the standard Order/OrderItem table layout, you already track all the purchases of every customer. What more do you need?

Answer (score 0):

When you make a purchase, you're really only inserting into two tables: Purchase and ObjectsList.

Querying for a Purchase and the Products in a Purchase is simple:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Purchase JOIN ObjectsList
        ON ( Purchase.idPurchase = ObjectsList.idPurchase )
    JOIN Product
        ON ( ObjectsList.idProduct = Product.idProduct )
WHERE idPurchase = ?;
```

I think your design is good, there's nothing wrong with needing to insert into or query multiple tables.